# Large data transfer between mobile app and a server

Tags: server, transfer-encoding

What's the server setup used for data communication between a mobile app (e.g. Android) and a server? Would an Apache http server with PHP be sufficient? Assume you need to transfer 1 GB of binary or text data once per day, or spread it out over small chunks and transfer at different times of the day. What about Tomcat + Java servlet?

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Your going to move 1Gb of data per day? Have you any idea how much this is going to cost in data charges from a mobile?

My own plan has an allowance of 1/2 a gig PER MONTH!

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

From the server side PHP/Apache should be fine, but is this all going to the same client?

Comment: should it be standard http or socket based

Comment: Ideally SOAP / HTTP (REST) based. Depends what you're doing - for instance for a project I am looking at I have had to write my own server program to simply monitor a network port and handle everything itself - but that was merely because this is the only way that the mobile device I was looking at would communicate with me...